# Ошибка запуска файла exe который был сделан библеотекой PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

При запуске консоли окно сразу закрывается
Код который я использовал для проверки

```
print('HELP')
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

test.py файл:

```
print('Help')
input()
```

Сборка EXE:

```
pyinstaller -w -F --console test.py
```

Резудьтат в dist: test.exe

После запуска из проводника программа отображает Help и ждёт ввода с консоли.

При запуске из консоли - тоже самое

PS: рекомендую создать виртуальное окружение (venv) и в нём уже установить pyinstaller. Тамже и собирать exe...